# How do I implement a score database in Android?

Tags: android, java, opengl-es, graphics-programming, databases

I making a 2D game for Android using OpenGL-ES technology. It is a space shooting game where the player shoots enemy ships.

I want to keep a track of score for the amount of enemy ships destroyed and a record of a local highscore. The score should be incremented whenever an enemy is destroyed. I also want a way of displaying both the current score and highscore on the game screen. I am not familiar with databases at all and I will appreciate a clear answer or a link to a good tutorial for my cause. Thanks.

Comment: Like this one? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 2):

Since it is local, your best bet would be to use the built in SQLite that is part of Android. Here is a link that I have used before and it explains how to use it pretty well.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview_sqlite

and also

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

It can get fairly complex if you are new to it but once you get the main code down it will be pretty quick to save and get data